# Why is a tuple containing an unhashable type unhashable?

Tags: python

For example, the tuple `(1,[0,1,2])`. I understand why from a design perspective; if the tuple were still hashable, then it would be trivial to make any unhashable type hashable by wrapping it in a tuple, which breaks the correct behavior of hashability, since you can change the value of the object without changing the hash value of the tuple. But if the tuple is not hashable, then I don't understand what makes an object hashable -- I thought it simply had to have `__hash__(self)` implemented, which tuple does.

Based on other answers I've looked at, and from testing examples, it seems that such an object is not hashable. It seems like sensible behavior would be for `tuple.__hash__()` to call `__hash__` for its component objects, but I don't understand how that would work from an implementation perspective, e.g. I don't know how a dictionary recognizes it as an unhashable type when it is still type tuple and tuple still defines `__hash__`.

Comment: "Why is a tuple containing an unhashable type unhashable?" the answer is in the question ;)

Comment: having a `__hash__` function defined doesn't mean all possible tuples are hashable. Like having the inverse function defined doesn't mean `0` has an inverse.

Comment: Also, you can easily define a custom class that implements `__hash__` but which is mutable. Of course, if you use instances of that class as dict keys or set items, and then mutate the instances, strange things may happen. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tuple` implements its own hash by computing and combining the hashes of the values it contains. When hashing one of those values fails, it lets the resulting exception propagate unimpeded.

Being unhashable just means calling `hash()` on you triggers a `TypeError`; one way to do that is to not define a `__hash__` method, but it works equally well if, in the course of your `__hash__` method you raise a `TypeError` (or any other error really) by some other means.

Basically, `tuple` is a hashable type (`isinstance((), collections.abc.Hashable)` is true, as is `isinstance(([],), collections.abc.Hashable)` because it's a type level check for the existence of `__hash__`), but if it stores unhashable types, any attempt to compute the hash will raise an exception at time of use, so it *behaves* like an unhashable type in that scenario.

Comment: I hadn't considered that "unhashable" means "generates an error on hashing" rather than "can't ever be hashed". It's very clear now, thanks! In fact, that explains why `d = {(1,[]) : 0}` raises `TypeError: unhashable type <list>` -- that exception was raised by `tuple.__hash__()`, not `dict.__hash__()`!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `tuple.__hash__()` calls `hash(item)` for each item in the tuple and then XOR's the results together. If one of the items isn't hashable, then that will raise a `TypeError` that bubbles up to the original caller.

Comment: It's [not just xoring (there is multiplication and some weird addition on each loop based on  length to dodge the flaws in naive xoring)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/tupleobject.c#L348), but yeah, that's the general idea.